# .NET timout when connecting to SQL Server database

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclient

I am aware that similar questions have been asked and answered regarding the error but after trying every single method I am still failing to run a query (takes ~2 mins to run on SQL) via .net.

The timeout occurs exactly in 30 seconds..

Basically I have made an application on vb.net that has a button that in turn calls a query. On pressing the button I get the error that says

> .net SqlClient data provider - Execution timeout expired

The default is 30 seconds.

Things I have already tried:

1. Changed timeout parameters in SQL Server Management
2. Changed timeout parameters in the vb code.
3. Unable to change registry level timeout parameters since I cant find the registry in HKLM..

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("EXECUTE QUARTERLY", con1)
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd1.CommandTimeout = 0
```

`con1` has the value

```
Data Source=localhost;Database=MY_DB;Integrated Security=True"
```

Any help is appreciated! Much thanks in advance

Comment: So it's not when *connecting* to the database?

Comment: In any case, if you want help with figuring out what is wrong with your code, you need to post your code.

Comment: The only thing that influences the timeout of the command is the `.CommandTimeout` property on the `SqlCommand` itself. You cannot set this globally.

Comment: How long takes to execute the query from SSMS? Btw. it is enough to setup timeout on the command class.

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic it takes approx 2 minutes.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes .CommantTimout is set to 0 in the code

Comment: Again, you will have to show the code.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes it is connected to the db and any query that runs <30 sec gets executed succesfully. Anything more throws this error

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen since it is a huge piece of code, I'll add the relevant bits

Comment: 30 seconds is default. Setup to zero. See more on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.8 A value of 0 indicates no limit (an attempt to execute a command will wait indefinitely).

Comment: I can confirm that a `.CommandTimeout` of 0 is respected by `SqlCommand`, so whatever you think is happening probably isn't happening.

Comment: This is the piece of code that calls the SQL Procedure called Quarterly.

Comment: You only have to post the execution code for the command, since it is a given that the SQL by itself works and just takes a long time, you can just use `= "long sql here";`.

Comment: Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("EXECUTE QUARTERLY", con1)
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd1.CommandTimeout = 0

Comment: Post it in the question, but if you set the timeout *after* you have executed it, then it is of course too late, it will already have crashed.

Comment: Editing the question

Comment: You should place command timeout BEFORE execution.

Comment: I have edited the question for better understanding

Comment: Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("EXECUTE QUARTERLY", con1) cmd1.CommandTimeout = 0    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: You need to move the line setting the timeout up above ExecuteNonQuery, code executes sequentially, it will first construct the command object, then try to execute it, this will crash, and thus it never gets to the line setting the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your lines and everything will be fine. 
Try this one

```
 Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("EXECUTE QUARTERLY", con1)
    cmd1.CommandTimeout = 0
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

See more on [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.8)